# How to shred XML with TSQL XQUERY

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I'm struggling to shred the following XML. I'm using Azure SQL database.

Here's my sample data and code attempt.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t ;
CREATE TABLE #t (XMLResult XML) ;
INSERT INTO #t (XMLResult)
VALUES (    '<testsuites>
                  <testsuite id="1" name="Verify" tests="1" errors="0" failures="1" timestamp="2021-12-08" time="0.000" hostname="" package="tSQLt">
                    <properties />
                    <testcase classname="Verify" name="Verify [Feature].[measure] format" time="0.000">
                      <failure message="Format incorrectly set." type="Failure" />
                    </testcase>
                  </testsuite>
                </testsuites>
                ') ; 

SELECT  T.* , 
        TS.H.value('name[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS [Test Method] , 
        TS.H.value('tests[1]', 'int') AS [Tests] , 
        TS.H.value('failures[1]', 'int') AS [Failures] , 
        TC.H.value('name[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)') AS [TestCase] , 
        TF.H.value('message[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)') AS [Failure Message] 
FROM    #t  T 
CROSS APPLY T.XMLResult.nodes('/testsuites/testsuite')          AS TS(H)
CROSS APPLY T.XMLResult.nodes('/testsuites/testsuite/testcase') AS TC(H)
CROSS APPLY T.XMLResult.nodes('/testsuites/testsuite/testcase/failure') AS TF(H)
 ;
```

Current output

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: All of the parts you want to get from the XML are properties, not values. `name[1]` should be `@name`, `tests[1]` should be `@tests`, etc. `name[1]` would be for extracting the value of a node *called* name (`<name>Value</name>`). *Though, in such a scenario, you should be using `(name/text())[1]`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have XML *attributes*, not *values*, which you are trying to retrieve. So you need to reference them with `@`

You are also using `.nodes` wrong: you should refer each one to the previous one. As it is, you are just cross-joining all the node levels together.

```sql
SELECT  --T.* , 
        TS.H.value('@name', 'varchar(255)') AS [Test Method] , 
        TS.H.value('@tests', 'int') AS [Tests] , 
        TS.H.value('@failures', 'int') AS [Failures] , 
        TC.H.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(255)') AS [TestCase] , 
        TF.H.value('@message', 'VARCHAR(255)') AS [Failure Message] 
FROM    #t  T 
CROSS APPLY T.XMLResult.nodes('/testsuites/testsuite')          AS TS(H)
CROSS APPLY TS.H.nodes('testcase') AS TC(H)
CROSS APPLY TC.H.nodes('failure') AS TF(H)
 ;
```

Note that if you are referring directly to an attribute of the current node (rather than a child node), you do not need the `[1]` predicate

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c2877370282e25ed82d1e90453b3130a)